# Error while build with cmake: undefined reference to `__imp__dupenv_s'

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference

I'm trying to download and use a library ([matplot++](https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus)), which doesn't have pre-compiled versions for my needs (Windows and MinGW compiler). The same thing had happen to me with another library (opencv), but I was able to compile it from source using CMake and following [this guide](https://medium.com/csmadeeasy/opencv-c-installation-on-windows-with-mingw-c0fc1499f39).

I tried to configure CMake both from the terminal and the gui and I get "Configuring done" and "Generating done" in both cases. However, when I try to build (`cmake --build .` or `mingw32-make install`) the build arrive to 4% and then I get this error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../../../source/matplot/libmatplot.a(gnuplot.cpp.obj):gnuplot.cpp:(.text+0x506d): undefined reference to `__imp__dupenv_s'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [examples\line_plot\plot\CMakeFiles\example_plot_1.dir\build.make:101: examples/line_plot/plot/example_plot_1.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4006: examples/line_plot/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_1.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

This is just my second time using cmake and I really don't understand how this works or what to do. I've searched online and on the github issues of matplot++, but I found nothing.

I'm using:
CMake version: 3.26.3
g++ (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
gcc (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0

full output

```
C:\Users\Daniele\Desktop\matplotplusplus-1.1.0\build>mingw32-make install
[  0%] Building CXX object source/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/nodesoup.dir/nodesoup/src/algebra.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object source/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/nodesoup.dir/nodesoup/src/fruchterman_reingold.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object source/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/nodesoup.dir/nodesoup/src/kamada_kawai.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object source/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/nodesoup.dir/nodesoup/src/layout.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object source/3rd_party/CMakeFiles/nodesoup.dir/nodesoup/src/nodesoup.cpp.obj
[  1%] Linking CXX static library libnodesoup.a
[  1%] Built target nodesoup
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/backend/backend_interface.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/backend/gnuplot.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/backend/backend_registry.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/axes_type.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/axes_object.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/axis_type.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/figure_type.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/figure_registry.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/legend.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/core/line_spec.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/colors.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/common.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/contourc.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/world_cities.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/world_map_10m.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/world_map_50m.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/util/world_map_110m.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/bars.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/box_chart.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/circles.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/contours.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/error_bar.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/filled_area.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/function_line.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/histogram.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/labels.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/line.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/matrix.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/network.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/parallel_lines.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/stair.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/string_function.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/surface.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/axes_objects/vectors.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/freestanding/axes_functions.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object source/matplot/CMakeFiles/matplot.dir/freestanding/histcounts.cpp.obj
[  4%] Linking CXX static library libmatplot.a
[  4%] Built target matplot
[  4%] Building CXX object test/generate_examples/CMakeFiles/generate_examples.dir/main.cpp.obj
[  4%] Linking CXX executable generate_examples.exe
[  4%] Built target generate_examples
[  4%] Building CXX object examples/line_plot/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_1.dir/plot_1.cpp.obj
[  4%] Linking CXX executable example_plot_1.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../../../source/matplot/libmatplot.a(gnuplot.cpp.obj):gnuplot.cpp:(.text+0x506d): undefined reference to `__imp__dupenv_s'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [examples\line_plot\plot\CMakeFiles\example_plot_1.dir\build.make:101: examples/line_plot/plot/example_plot_1.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4006: examples/line_plot/plot/CMakeFiles/example_plot_1.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: "_However, when I try to build (cmake --build . or mingw32-make install_" derp. why are you trying to install when your build fails?

Comment: I really don’t know, I just followed the steps that are in the guide I’ve linked. What I meant was that both “cmake -- build .” and “mingw32-make install” produces the same output.